# OpenCV unable to reference extended modules

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to set-up OpenCV on Ubuntu 16.04 with C++. I have managed to get the program to work with the default OpenCV modules, but am having difficulties with the extended modules. For example, I want to use the following code to generate super pixels:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ximgproc/slic.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ximgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  Mat *image;
  *image = imread("shoe.jpg" , cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
  Ptr<ximgproc::SuperpixelSLIC> ptr =
                    ximgproc::createSuperpixelSLIC(*image,100,10, 10.0f);
}
```

When I compile with this line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp  -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccnStIaV.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `cv::ximgproc::createSuperpixelSLIC(cv::_InputArray const&, int, int, float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I believe this is an issue with the file opencv.pc in my pkgconfigs file. For some reason when I build the extended modules, the opencv.pc file does not get modified to include ximgproc and other modules. When I run the `pkg-config --libs opencv` command, I get the same libraries listed as when I installed just the base version of OpenCV:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so -lopencv_calib3d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so -lopencv_contrib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -lopencv_core /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so -lopencv_features2d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so -lopencv_flann /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so -lopencv_gpu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so -lopencv_highgui /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so -lopencv_imgproc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so -lopencv_legacy /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so -lopencv_ml /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so -lopencv_objdetect /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so -lopencv_ocl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so -lopencv_photo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so -lopencv_stitching /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so -lopencv_superres /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so -lopencv_ts /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so -lopencv_video /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so -lopencv_videostab
```

I suppose I could go into the opencv.pc file and manually add all the extended module paths, but the fact that this wasn't done automatically suggests to me that I am doing something wrong during installation.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this problem. I've been stuck on this set-up for the last couple of days and would love to get to image processing :)

Comment: Do you use cmake for building OpenCV with opencv_contrib modules?

Comment: Yes, I ran `cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules ..`. After which, I ran `make -j4`. The second command completed without any interruptions.

Comment: Try to run `sudo make install` after `make -j4`, or specify path of opencv in your proejct's cmake file

Comment: sudo make install, did not change the outcome. Which projects cmake file should I be specifying the path?

Comment: I faced the same problem and follow @DmitriiZ. I ran `sudo make install` at build folder of OpenCV, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks made a silly error during instillation.

I forgot to make sure the version of the extended modules was the same as the version of the base OpenCV library. Make sure they are the same version.

For reference, if you are building from the Github repositories, you have to run `git checkout x.x.x` in both opencv and opencv_contrib. Both 'x.x.x' need to be the same.